# column '_id' does not exist, nested query's

Tags: java, android, sqlite, cursor

i know that there are a lot of post about this problem, but i can't find the solutions. So i'm sorry for a duplicate.

Here is my database code:

```
    public static final String DATABASE_NAME = "MyGames.db";

public static final String TABEL_CONSOLE = "Consol_table";
    public static final String COL_CONSOLE_ID = "_id";
    public static final String COL_CONSOLE_NAME = "NAME";
    public static final String COL_CONSOLE_PRODUCER = "PRODUCER";
    public static final String COL_CONSOLE_GENERATION = "GENERATION";
    public static final String COL_CONSOLE_TYPE = "TYPE";
    public static final String COL_CONSOLE_PUBLICATION = "PUBLICATION";
    public static final String COL_CONSOLE_ADDED = "ADDED";

public static final String TABEL_VIDEOGAME = "Videogame_table";
    public static final String COL_VIDEOGAME_ID = "_id";
    public static final String COL_VIDEOGAME_NAME = "NAME";
    public static final String COL_VIDEOGAME_GENRE = "GENRE";
    public static final String COL_VIDEOGAME_DEVELOPER = "DEVELOPER";
    public static final String COL_VIDEOGAME_PRODUCER = "PRODUCER";
    public static final String COL_VIDEOGAME_PUBLICATION = "PUBLICATION";
    public static final String COL_VIDEOGAME_ADDED = "ADDED";

public static final String TABEL_GENRE = "Genere_table";
    public static final String COL_GENRE_ID = "_id";
    public static final String COL_GENRE_NAME = "NAME";

public static final String TABEL_VIDEOGAME_PLATFORM = "Videogameplatform_table";
    public static final String COL_VIDEOGAME_PLATFORM_ID = "_id";
    public static final String COL_VIDEOGAME_PLATFORM_VIDEOGAME_ID = "VIDEOGAME_id";
    public static final String COL_VIDEOGAME_PLATFORM_CONSOLE_ID = "CONSOLE_id";

public DataBase(Context context) {
    super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, 1);

}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    createConsoleTable(db);
    createVideoGameTable(db);
    createGenreTable(db);
    createVideoGamePlatformTable(db);

}

private void createVideoGamePlatformTable(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    db.execSQL("create table " + TABEL_VIDEOGAME_PLATFORM + "(" +
            COL_VIDEOGAME_PLATFORM_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT," +
            COL_VIDEOGAME_PLATFORM_VIDEOGAME_ID + " INTEGER NOT NULL," +
            COL_VIDEOGAME_PLATFORM_CONSOLE_ID + " INTEGER NOT NULL," +
            "FOREIGN KEY( " + COL_VIDEOGAME_PLATFORM_VIDEOGAME_ID + " ) REFERENCES " + TABEL_VIDEOGAME + " (" + COL_VIDEOGAME_ID + " )" +
            "FOREIGN KEY( " + COL_VIDEOGAME_PLATFORM_CONSOLE_ID + " ) REFERENCES " + TABEL_CONSOLE + " (" + COL_CONSOLE_ID + " )" +
            ");");

    db.execSQL("INSERT INTO " + TABEL_VIDEOGAME_PLATFORM + "(" +
                    COL_VIDEOGAME_PLATFORM_VIDEOGAME_ID + "," +
                    COL_VIDEOGAME_PLATFORM_CONSOLE_ID + ")" +
                    "VALUES " +
                    "('0', '0')," +
                    "('0', '2')," +
                    "('0', '7')," +
                    "('1', '0')," +
                    "('1', '2')," +
                    "('1', '7')," +
                    "('2', '2')," +
                    "('3', '6')," +
                    "('4', '9')," +
                    "('5', '0')," +
                    "('5', '2')," +
                    "('5', '7');"
    );



}

private void createGenreTable(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    db.execSQL("create table " + TABEL_GENRE + "(" +
            COL_GENRE_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT," +
            COL_GENRE_NAME + " TEXT(40) NOT NULL" +
            ");");

    db.execSQL("INSERT INTO " + TABEL_GENRE + "(" +
            COL_GENRE_NAME + ")" +
                    "VALUES " +
                    "('GDR'), " +
                    "('FPS'), " +
                    "('TPS'), " +
                    "('Platform')" +
                    ";"


    );
}

private void createVideoGameTable(SQLiteDatabase db) {

    db.execSQL("create table " + TABEL_VIDEOGAME + "(" +
            COL_VIDEOGAME_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT," +
            COL_VIDEOGAME_NAME + " TEXT(40) NOT NULL," +
            COL_VIDEOGAME_GENRE + " INTEGER," +

            COL_VIDEOGAME_DEVELOPER + " TEXT(25)," +
            COL_VIDEOGAME_PRODUCER + " TEXT(25)," +
            COL_VIDEOGAME_PUBLICATION + " TEXT(15)," +
            COL_VIDEOGAME_ADDED + " INTEGER," +
            "FOREIGN KEY( " + COL_VIDEOGAME_GENRE + " ) REFERENCES " + TABEL_GENRE + " (" + COL_GENRE_ID + " )" +
            ");");

    db.execSQL("INSERT INTO " + TABEL_VIDEOGAME + " (" +
            COL_VIDEOGAME_NAME + "," +
            COL_VIDEOGAME_GENRE + "," +
            COL_VIDEOGAME_DEVELOPER + "," +
            COL_VIDEOGAME_PRODUCER + "," +
            COL_VIDEOGAME_PUBLICATION + ","+
            COL_CONSOLE_ADDED + ")" +
            "VALUES " +
            "('Mass Effect', '0', 'BioWare', 'Eletronic Arts ','2007', '0')," +
            "('Mass Effect 2', '0',  'BioWare', 'Eletronic Arts ','2011', '0')," +

            "('Uncharted 3', '2', 'NaugtyDog', 'Sony ','2012', '0')," +
            "('Halo 5', '1', 'Bungie', 'Microsoft','2015', '0')," +
            "('Mario', '3', 'Nintendo', 'Nintendo ','2015', '0')," +

            "('Mass Effect 3', '0', 'BioWare', 'Eletronic Arts ','2013', '0')" +


                    ";"
    );
}

private void createConsoleTable(SQLiteDatabase db) {

    db.execSQL("create table " + TABEL_CONSOLE + "( " +
            COL_CONSOLE_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT," +
            COL_CONSOLE_NAME + " TEXT(40) NOT NULL," +
            COL_CONSOLE_PRODUCER + " TEX(40)," +
            COL_CONSOLE_GENERATION + " TEXT(15)," +
            COL_CONSOLE_TYPE + " TEXT(15)," +
            COL_CONSOLE_PUBLICATION + " TEXT(15)," +
            COL_CONSOLE_ADDED + " INTEGER" +
            ");");



    db.execSQL("INSERT INTO " + TABEL_CONSOLE + " ( " +
                    COL_CONSOLE_NAME + "," +
                    COL_CONSOLE_PRODUCER + "," +
                    COL_CONSOLE_GENERATION + "," +
                    COL_CONSOLE_TYPE + "," +
                    COL_CONSOLE_PUBLICATION + "," +
                    COL_CONSOLE_ADDED + ")" +
                    "VALUES ('PC', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', '0')," +                     //0
                    "('Playstation 4', 'Sony', 'Octave', 'Home', ' ', '0')," + //1
                    "('Playstation 3', 'Sony', 'Seventh', 'Home', ' ', '0')," + //2
                    "('Playstation 2', 'Sony', 'Sixth', 'Home', ' ', '0')," + //3
                    "('Playstation 1', 'Sony', 'fifth', 'Home', ' ', '0')," + //4
                    "('Playstation Vita', 'Sony', 'Octave', 'Home', ' ', '0')," +  //5
                    "('XboxOne', 'Microsoft', 'Octave', 'Home', ' ', '0')," + //6
                    "('Xbox 360', 'Microsoft', 'Seventh', 'Home', ' ', '0')," +  //7
                    "('WiiU', 'Nintendo', 'Octave', 'Home', ' ', '0')," + //8
                    "('Wii', 'Nintendo', 'Seventh', 'Home', ' ', '0')," + //9
                    "('Playstation Portable', 'Sony', 'Seventh', 'Home', ' ', '0')" + //10
                    ";"
    );

}
```

Here is where call th SimpleCursorAdapter :

```
 ListView consoleGames = (ListView) popupView.findViewById(R.id.listView_all_games);
    Cursor cursor = myDb.getConsoleGames(console);
    String[] fromFieldNames = new String[]{DataBase.COL_VIDEOGAME_NAME};
    int[] toViewsIDs = new int[]{R.id.textViewGameName};

    SimpleCursorAdapter myCursorAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(popupView.getContext(), R.layout.item_all_games_list, cursor, fromFieldNames, toViewsIDs, 0);
    consoleGames.setAdapter(myCursorAdapter);
```

And here is the query

```
    public Cursor getConsoleGames(String console) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    final String query1 = "select " +  COL_CONSOLE_ID + " from " + TABEL_CONSOLE + " WHERE " + COL_CONSOLE_NAME + " like " + "'" + console + "'";
    final String query2 = "select " + COL_VIDEOGAME_PLATFORM_VIDEOGAME_ID + " from " + TABEL_VIDEOGAME_PLATFORM + " WHERE " + COL_VIDEOGAME_PLATFORM_CONSOLE_ID + " = ( " + query1 + ")";

    String query = "select " + COL_VIDEOGAME_NAME + " from " + TABEL_VIDEOGAME + " WHERE " + COL_VIDEOGAME_ID + " = ( " + query2 + ");"  ;




    Cursor res = db.rawQuery(query, null);

    return res;
}
```

And this is the LogCat:

```
12-14 12:14:14.894 6607-6607/com.tutecentral.mygames E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                   Process: com.tutecentral.mygames, PID: 6607
                                                                   java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: column '_id' does not exist
                                                                       at android.database.AbstractCursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(AbstractCursor.java:303)
                                                                       at android.support.v4.widget.CursorAdapter.init(CursorAdapter.java:174)
                                                                       at android.support.v4.widget.CursorAdapter.<init>(CursorAdapter.java:151)
                                                                       at android.support.v4.widget.ResourceCursorAdapter.<init>(ResourceCursorAdapter.java:93)
                                                                       at android.support.v4.widget.SimpleCursorAdapter.<init>(SimpleCursorAdapter.java:89)
                                                                       at com.tutecentral.mygames.MainActivity.popUpAddGameEvent(MainActivity.java:157)
                                                                       at com.tutecentral.mygames.MainActivity.showPopUpAddGame(MainActivity.java:143)
                                                                       at com.tutecentral.mygames.MainActivity.access$200(MainActivity.java:40)
                                                                       at com.tutecentral.mygames.MainActivity$2.onClick(MainActivity.java:124)
                                                                       at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4820)
                                                                       at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:20157)
                                                                       at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:815)
                                                                       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:104)
                                                                       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:194)
                                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5578)
                                                                       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
                                                                       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:955)
                                                                       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:750)
```

How can i fix this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is with your query. you are using a `CursorAdapter`, and it expects to find the column `_id` as part of the cursor you are feeding it with. Add it to your query. E.g.

```
String query = "select " + COL_VIDEOGAME_ID + "," + COL_VIDEOGAME_NAME + " from " + TABEL_VIDEOGAME + " WHERE " + COL_VIDEOGAME_ID + " = ( " + query2 + ");"  ;
```